# org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean cannot be cast to org.hibernate.SessionFactory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I am trying to integrate Spring-MVC with Hibernate(ie-HibernateTemplate)
but got stuck with this **ClassCastException** ie *org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean cannot be cast to org.hibernate.SessionFactory*.
I am implementing -HibernateTemplate,HibernateTransactionManager,LocalSessionFactoryBean using Hibernate-4 (ie-org.springframework.orm.hibernate4 package).

I am not able to do Dependency Injection of LocalSessionFactoryBean into  HibernateTemplate and HibernateTransactionManager 
ie- Casting fails for LocalSessionFactoryBean(org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean) to SessionFactory(org.hibernate.SessionFactory)
but this Dependency Injection has been recommended by Spring.

[project-structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxqbL.png)

---

POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringMVC_HibernateTemp2</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>SpringMVC_HibernateTemp2 Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.16</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-expression -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.39</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-dbcp -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.65</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Its for Spring-jdbc template -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Its is for Hibernate template -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.transaction/jta -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>SpringMVC_HibernateTemp2</finalName>
</build>
```

---

index.jsp

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Welcome to Spring CRUD operation using jdbc</h2>
<marquee><h4>Welcome Admin</h4></marquee>
<form action="./addemp.htm">
Enter id : <input type="text" name="id">
Enter name : <input type="text" name="name">
Enter Salary : <input type="text" name="salary">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
    <web-app>
     <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
   </web-app>
```

---

MyConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({ "com.spring" })
public class MyConfig {

    @Bean(name = "bds")
    public BasicDataSource m1() {
        System.out.println("Basic data source started..........");
        BasicDataSource bds = new BasicDataSource();
        bds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        bds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysqldb");
        bds.setUsername("root");
        bds.setPassword("root");
        System.out.println("Basic data source end..........");
        return bds;
    }

    @Bean(name = "LocalSF")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean m12() {
        System.out.println(" local SF started...");
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sf = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        MyConfig conf = new MyConfig();
        BasicDataSource bds1 = conf.m1();
        sf.setDataSource(bds1);// property 1
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        prop.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
        prop.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        prop.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        sf.setHibernateProperties(prop); // property 2
        sf.setAnnotatedClasses(Employee.class); // property 3
        System.out.println(" local SF end...");
        return sf;
    }

    @Bean(name = "txManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager m13() {
        System.out.println("Tranx Manager started....");
        HibernateTransactionManager htm = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        MyConfig conf = new MyConfig();
        LocalSessionFactoryBean lsf = conf.m12();
        htm.setSessionFactory((SessionFactory) lsf);
        System.out.println("tranx Manager end....");
        return htm;
    }

    @Bean(name = "hiberTemp")
    public HibernateTemplate m14() {
        System.out.println("hibernate template started...");
        HibernateTemplate ht = new HibernateTemplate();
        MyConfig conf = new MyConfig();
        LocalSessionFactoryBean lsf = conf.m12();
        SessionFactory sf = (SessionFactory) lsf;
        ht.setSessionFactory(sf);
        System.out.println("hibernate template end...");
        return ht;
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver m2() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver ivr = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        ivr.setPrefix("/output/");
        ivr.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return ivr;
    }

}
```

---

MyWebInitializer.java

```
public class MyWebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { MyConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "*.htm" };
    }

}
```

---

EmpController.java

```
@Controller(value = "empcontr")
public class EmpController {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "servimp")
    private EmpService empserv;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addemp.htm")
    public ModelAndView m1(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws SQLException {
        String eid = req.getParameter("id");
        String ename = req.getParameter("name");
        String salary = req.getParameter("salary");

        Employee e1 = new Employee();
        e1.setEid(Integer.parseInt(eid));
        e1.setEname(ename);
        e1.setSalary(Double.parseDouble(salary));

        int i = empserv.saveEmp(e1);
        System.out.println(i + " Inserted..");
        ModelAndView mav = null;
        return mav = i != 0 ? new ModelAndView("success") : new ModelAndView("failure");
    }

}
```

---

EmpService.java

```
public interface EmpService {
 public int saveEmp(Employee e) throws SQLException;
}
```

---

EmpServiceImpl.java

```
@Service(value = "servimp")
public class EmpServiceImpl implements EmpService {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "daoimp")
    private EmpDAO edao;

    public int saveEmp(Employee e) throws SQLException {
        return edao.addEmp(e);
    }
}
```

---

EmpDAO.java

```
public interface EmpDAO {
    public int addEmp(Employee e) throws SQLException;
}
```

---

EmpDAOImpl.java

```
@Repository(value = "daoimp")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
public class EmpDAOImpl implements EmpDAO {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "hiberTemp")
    private HibernateTemplate ht;

    public int addEmp(Employee e) throws SQLException {
        int i = (Integer) ht.save(e);
        return i;
    }

}
```

---

Employee.java

```
@Setter @Getter @ToString
@Entity
@Table(name="employee_table1")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    private int eid;
    private String ename;
    private double salary;

}
```

---

I have analyzed this Casting problem as mentioned above.
Is anything wrong with my maven dependency configuration, Dependency Injection in bean,etc..
I have tried reading many posts about this, but nothing helped me. Am I just missing something?

This is my first Spring-MVC/Hibernate project from-scratch.
Please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot cast a `LocalSessionFactoryBean` to `SessionFactory`, it does not extend it or implement, however, `LocalSessionFactoryBean` si a `Factory<>` object of type `SessionFactory`, `Factory<SessionFactory>`. If you ctrl+click on the class `LocalSessionFactoryBean`, you can see that for yourself, you can also see that it has a `SessionFactory` object declared and that `getObject()` method returns it.
So, your code should be:

```
    @Bean(name = "hiberTemp")
    public HibernateTemplate m14() {
      System.out.println("hibernate template started...");
      HibernateTemplate ht = new HibernateTemplate();
      MyConfig conf = new MyConfig();
      LocalSessionFactoryBean lsf = conf.m12();
      SessionFactory sf = 1sf.getObject();
      ht.setSessionFactory(sf);
      System.out.println("hibernate template end...");
      return ht;
}
```

Comment: You have said correctly -> In order to obtain SessionFactory Object we need to invoke getObject() method i.e-LocalSessionFactoryBean.getObject();
Thanks for ur help, It helped me partially to solve this problem.

Comment: @SabunkarTejasSahailesh, that's great

Answer (score 2):

I have re-written the following files:

1. MyConfig.java
2. EmpDAOImpl.java

All the other files are same as mentioned in question statement.

---

MyConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)
@ComponentScan({ "com.spring" })
public class MyConfig implements TransactionManagementConfigurer {

    @Bean(name = "bds")
    public BasicDataSource basicDataSource() {
        System.out.println("Basic data source started..........");
        BasicDataSource bds = new BasicDataSource();
        bds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        bds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysqldb");
        bds.setUsername("root");
        bds.setPassword("root");
        System.out.println("Basic data source end..........");
        return bds;
    }

    @Bean(name = "LocalSF")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactory() throws IOException {
        System.out.println(" local SF started...");
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sf = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sf.setDataSource(basicDataSource());// property 1
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        prop.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        prop.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        prop.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        sf.setHibernateProperties(prop); // property 2
        sf.setAnnotatedClasses(Employee.class); // property 3
        System.out.println(" local SF end...");
        sf.afterPropertiesSet();

        return sf;
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        System.out.println("Tranx Manager started....");
        HibernateTransactionManager htm = new HibernateTransactionManager();

        try {
            SessionFactory sf = localSessionFactory().getObject();
            htm.setSessionFactory(sf);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("tranx Manager end....");
        return htm;
    }

    @Bean(name = "hiberTemp")
    public HibernateTemplate m14() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("hibernate template started...");
        HibernateTemplate ht = new HibernateTemplate();
        SessionFactory sf = localSessionFactory().getObject();
        ht.setSessionFactory(sf);

        System.out.println("hibernate template end...");
        return ht;
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver internalViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver ivr = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        ivr.setPrefix("/output/");
        ivr.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return ivr;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager annotationDrivenTransactionManager() {
        return transactionManager();
    }

}
```

---

EmpDAOImpl.java

```
@Repository(value = "daoimp")
@Transactional
public class EmpDAOImpl implements EmpDAO {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "hiberTemp")
    private HibernateTemplate ht;

    public int addEmp(Employee e) throws SQLException {
        int i = (Integer) ht.save(e);

        return i;
    }
}
```

---

Please provide me suggestion if any correction required for above code.
Thank you all for your suggestions.

Comment: what does `afterPropertiesSet()` do? I was missing that step and now it's working for me. I see this in whenever I manually try to configure a bean. Any thoughts on this?